# If I change the width value with JavaScript in Bootstrap, the column function does not work

Tags: javascript, css, sass, frameworks, bootstrap-5

To briefly explain, dragging the division changes the width (%) of 'nav' and 'section' in javascript.

When dragging the division, the width value of the window changes, but the function of the column in Bootstrap does not work.

It is my code.

-html

```
<nav id="nav_panel" class="h-100 bg-light" style="width:29%"> ... </nav>
<div id="division"></div>
<section id="section" class="h-100 pb-3 ps-3" style="width:70%"> ...</section>
```

-js

```
var start_pos, diff_pos = 0;
var is_mouse_down = false;
var is_mouse_move = false;
const width = {
  legt: null,
  right: null
}
var nav = document.getElementById('nav_panel');
var content = document.getElementById('section');
var division = document.getElementById('division');

const mousedown = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const el = e.target;
  if (el.id == 'division') {
    start_pos = e.clientX;
    width.left = nav.clientWidth;
    width.right =content.clientWidth;
    console.log(width.left, width.right);
    is_mouse_down = true;
  }
}

const mousemove = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (is_mouse_down) {
        is_mouse_move = true;
        diff_pos = event.clientX - start_pos;
        var sum = width.left+width.right+division.clientWidth;
        nav.style.width = ((width.left + diff_pos-division.clientWidth)*100/sum)+'%';
        content.style.width = ((width.right - diff_pos)*100/sum)+'%';

  }
}
const mouseup = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(is_mouse_down){
    is_mouse_down = false;
    if(is_mouse_move){
      is_mouse_move=false;
      pos = e.clientX - start_pos;
      var sum = width.left + width.right + division.clientWidth;

      nav.style.width = ((width.left + diff_pos - division.clientWidth)*100/sum)+'%';
      content.style.width = ((width.right - diff_pos)*100/sum)+'%';
      
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown)
window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup)
```

- This is the default state.

[image]

- This is when the browser window is reduced. The number of columns has been reduced from 4 to 2.

[image]

- This is when the window width is reduced by dragging the division. The goal is to reduce the column to two, but still four.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does changing directly in html `style="width:29%"` to different values also causes the bug?

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the value directly in the html, the same symptom exists!

Comment: So I guess JavaScript is irrelevant here. Include more of the html structure

Comment: Both? So, do I need to find something in Bootstrap?
or
Shouldn't I be using style(width)?

Comment: "The width CSS media feature can be used to test the width of the viewport", it does not test the width of it's parent, it ain't a container query.